# 3 finger swipe up / down in Finder not working Catalina

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

System Preferences > Trackpad > Swipe between pages > Swipe with 2 or 3 fingers

I am able to swipe sideways but not up and down in Finder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an up/down swipe gesture to navigate pages - these clash with other swipe gestures like `app expose` and `mission control`.

So, to find other options:

- Why would you need to swipe up/down in Finder?
- Are you trying to switch between different windows of Finder or trying to switch to another app?

If you are trying to switch to a different window of Finder, you can press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or use `app expose`'s three/four finger swipe down. These commands/swipes work for all applications, not just Finder.

If you want to switch to a different application you can press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or use `mission control`'s three/four finger swipe up.

If you're in Finder's list view and are trying to collapse/expand a folder, you can just press the <kbd>Left</kbd> key to collapse the selected folder or press the <kbd>Right</kbd> key to expand the selected folder.

Comment: Up and down to switch files/folders in column view. Same as up/down to switch messages in Mail.

Comment: If you're using column view, you would just use the left/right keys to navigate in or out of the file directory.

Comment: I could swipe up or down with 3 fingers in Mavericks and go through the files/folders in the list. I can do it in Mail in Catalina right now. 3 finger swipe left/right navigates left & right through the columns/folders as it should. 3 finger swipe up/down no longer works.

Comment: Just doing a quick google search (not extensive search mind you), but it doesn't seem like it's been supported like that for a while? I know that Mavericks had far less swipe gestures than Catalina or even Mojave/High Sierra, so its possible this is no longer a feature in later systems. that said, there is software like Better Touch Tool(?) that can be programmed to map different swipe gestures to your liking. Not sure if that helps, but I just don't think there is a similar system setting in Catalina

Comment: Yeah BTT is amazing. I have it for Mavericks, not for Catalina. There's gotta be a way to bring that back. 3 finger swiping through Finder is a breeze. Not just left/right through folders but up/down through files. I'm on a real customization kick on this Catalina partition. But 3 finger swipe up/down is such a handy feature that I'm surprised (a) it's gone, and (b) that I'm talking with some helpful human on StackExchange that hasn't used it... I thought it was one of the main reasons why people use Macs...ha...

Comment: Haha, yeah I've never noticed/used it to be honest. I rarely use any swipe gestures except mission control and swiping between different desktop windows. If I have to navigate in/out of folders or pages, I just use keyboard shortcuts. Besides, I can't be too reliant on them, because I do interact with non-trackpad Macs often ;)

Comment: I hear ya. Not me though, my hand dances across this trackpad like Tom Cruise in Minority Report. I will find or hack this feature back into the system.